# How to return polymorphic classes based on a string identifier in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I have a Java class to create polymorphic classes. For example:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public void bar()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

class A extends Foo
{
    public void uniqueMethod()
    {
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

There are many, many classes that extend this class. Each class must be instantiated dependent on a string. For example, the string "A" may indicate we need the class A.

I was hoping to have a creator class that can create the classes, something like:

```
A myClass = (A)Creator::create( "AAA" );
```

I cannot do a switch statement because this must be easily extensible. It is required that others may simply add a class that extends Foo and provide the identifier. Something like:

```
Creator::add( "BBB", B.class );
B myClass = (B)Creator::create( "BBB" );
```

I have encountered similar syntax in Java, but I am still fairly new. How can I achieve something similar to this? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: not sure what you want, but you may want to read about `Class.forName` method and also about "Factories" (https://duckduckgo.com/?q=abstract+factory)

Comment: Just use a `Map<String, Class<? extends Foo>>` and the `newInstance()` reflective method.

Comment: If you put all the classes inside the same package you can use `Class.forName("myPackage"+className).newInstance()` needs default constructor. If not @BoristheSpider 's comment is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

What you're looking for is the `Class` class, under `java.lang`. Use the `forName` method to get a class dynamically, like:

```
String classID = "your.fully.qualified.class.name";
Class c = Class.forName(classID);
Foo polymorphicSubclass = c.newInstance();
```

Comment: `Welcome to StackOverflow!` this is what we should say to you :D

Comment: @Jari it says member for 6 months :P